# Assembly Code Behaves Funny / Unexpected - ASM x86-64 Bit (AT&T, GAS)

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, x86-64, gnu-assembler

### My setup

- **OS:** ------------------ Linux
- **Architecture:** ------ x86-64
- **Syntax:** ------------ AT&T
- **Compiler:** --------- GAS

---

### My code

(explanation below)

```bash
.section .text
.globl _start
print:
  movq $1, %rax
  movq $1, %rdi
  movq %rsp, %rsi
  popq %rbx
  popq %rdx

  # Useless Instructions...
  xor %rcx, %rcx    # 36
  xor %rcx, %rcx    # 39
  xor %rcx, %rcx    # 42
  xor %rcx, %rcx    # 45
  xor %rcx, %rcx    # 48
  xor %rcx, %rcx    # 51
  xor %rcx, %rcx    # 54
  xor %rcx, %rcx    # 57
  xor %rcx, %rcx    # 60
  xor %rcx, %rcx    # 63
  xor %rcx, %rcx    # 66

  syscall
  jmp end
  ret

_start:
  pushq $66
  pushq $1
  call print
end:
  movq $60, %rax
  xor %rdi, %rdi
  syscall
```

Output: "B"

---

### Explanation

Okay here comes the thing. As you see, I want to:

1. **Push** `$66` (`$'B'`) to the stack
2. **Call** the `print` function
3. **Mov** the `$66` into the `%rsi` register
4. **Write** to `STDOUT` with the linux `syscall 1`, which is the linux _write syscall
5. **Jmp** to the *end* label, otherwise the `Error: segmentation fault (core dumped)` gets raised

---

---

#### What's wrong

I expect it to output "B", which it does. So where is the problem you may ask? You probably already saw that bunch of `xor %rcx, %rcx`'s.

Let me explain what they do:

- For some reason it starts at `33` ("!")
- For every instruction I add to this code, it adds `3` to this number
- So I added `11` instructions, and the `33` became `66` (33 + 11*3 = 66), which is "B" in ASCII

**Without the 11 `xor`-instructions, it prints "!" which has the ASCII value of 33.**

Note: `xor %rcx, %rcx` is just some instruction. It can be every instruction and every instruction has the value of `3`.

---

#### That means

I can add as many instructions as I want, to print every ASCII value over 33.

###### Example:

If I want to echo an "H", all I have to do is to add 2 more `xor %rcx, %rcx` instructions.

Calculation: `66` ("B") + `3` (1 instruction) + `3` (1 instruction) = `72` ("H")

---

---

## Final Question

Why? Just why? I just started with `x86 ASM`, so I am completely new to it. There are clearly some obvious things I am missing here... I just played around a bit and stumbled across this.

Can you help me answer these questions?

1. **How does it work?**
2. **How can it affect the output / RSI register?**
3. **Why does it start at 33?**
4. **Any ideas on how to fix this?**

My guess is, it has to do something with the **Instruction Pointer**, but I have no clue...

---

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `call print` places a return address on the stack. You then print that. Of course that return address points to after the `call` which is affected by how much code you have. The `3` is because the `xor %rcx, %rcx` is 3 bytes. Other instructions are not 3 bytes. 64 bit calling convention does not pass arguments on the stack but you are of course free to invent your own. To fix the code you can do `lea 16(%rsp), %rsi`

Comment: @Jester Omg thanks, ofc that makes so much sense now^^ I bet for someone like you who has so much experience on ASM, questions like this must annoy you, sry for that ^^ And 2 more questions, just to be clear: `1.` It is `16(%rsp)`, because the one `pushq` and the `call` both push 8 Bytes onto the stack, and you want to access the Bytes after the `16 Bytes`. `2.` You don't use the stack, cuz you use the `rdi, rsi, rdx...` registers for arguments. Did I understand everything right? :))

Comment: Yes that is correct. It is not annoying, we are here to help :)

Comment: @Jester Wow **Assembly Language** is so much fun :D I still have so much to learn^^ But I really fell in love with it^^  And really thanks for your help and your kindness :)

Comment: There are some good resources linked from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info, including a section at the bottom on using GDB to single-step and watch register values change.  Also worth watching Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk “[What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4)”.  (See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116))

Comment: @Jester don't you want to write a short answer so I can close this question?^^ You would get `+25 Rep` :)